# Difficulty with find_all in BS4

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup 4 to scrape some text from a webpage into a Discord bot.

```
@commands.command(hidden=True)
async def roster(self):
"""A script using BS4."""

url = "http://www.clandestine.pw/roster.html"
async with aiohttp.get(url) as response:
    soupObject = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "html.parser")
try:
    txt = soupObject.find("font", attrs={'size': '4'}).get_text()
    await self.bot.say(txt)
except:
    await self.bot.say("Not found!")
```

Running the command, this returns "ThaIIen" (as it should). If I simply change `find` to `find_all`, it returns "Not found!" Why? Shouldn't that return every font size 4 text in the document?

Answer (score 1):

`find_all("font", attrs={'size': '4'})` will return:

```
[font_tag1, font_tag2, font_tag3 ....]
```

`find("font", attrs={'size': '4'})` will return:

```
font_tag1
```

`.get_text()` is the method of tag object, not the list the object, so, when you run the `find_all().get_text()` will raise an `Exception`